# Calculating convolution of two kernel density estimators in Java

Tags: java, convolution, kernel-density

I need to calcualte kernel density estimators of two variables X and Y (both 1 dimensional), as well as the convolution of the two (the kernel density estimator for X+Y).

I have been looking for any Kernel Density Estimation Java library that offers functionality for calculating the convolution of two kernel densities, but have been unsuccesful so far. Am I missing something, or is there no other way than to implement this myself?

Comment: So you are saying that the first links produced by Google are all "not good enough"?

Comment: Note that I do not have any observations for X+Y, only for X and Y themselves. Therefore the kernel density estimation for X+Y can only be calculated from the kernel density estimation over X and the kernel density estimation over Y through convolution. The first few links produced by google (Weka, BEAST-MCMC and okde-java, etc.) all do not seem to offer functionality for this convolution step.